# Force HTTPS except with certain directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using the following .htaccess file to force any page request to https://

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

How could I modify this script to continue to force https:// except in specified directories like http://example.com/api/ ("api" folder)?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yournonhttpsdirectory/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.xyz/$1 [R,L]
```

maybe this might work?

Comment: I still want to force HTTPS throughout the entire website, just not in a certain directory.